# how to ignore specific error in pyre-check python package for the whole project

Tags: python, pyre-check, pysa

I am using pyre-checking for static type testing, I want to ignore specific error from my project.

For example: Undefined attribute [16]: Module `google.protobuf.struct_pb2` has no attribute `_STRUCT`.

Suppose if I want to  ignore this error from my project how can I do it?

Answer (score 8):

I am not familiar with your project but you have more options. I guess you can select the proper one for you.

You can suppress a specific error in your code with the following commented-out line:

```
# pyre-ignore[16]:
That part which raises the error
```

or

```
That part which raises the error  # pyre-ignore[16]
```

---

You can suppress all errors in your file if you declare the following commented-out line at beginning of your Python file:

```
# pyre-ignore-all-errors
```

---

You can exclude the problematic file or files with a regex (It is not totally recommended because the other errors also will be suppressed).

You can do it 2 ways:

1. Put the `exclude` parameter to your PyRe config file (`.pyre_configuration`)
2. Use the `exclude` argument in command line (`--exclude EXCLUDE     Exclude files and directories matching this regexp from parsing`)

---

Honestly, I think your want to disable completely the `Undefined attribute [16]` error in your analysis but unfortunately currently this option is not supported by PyRe. Perhaps if you rewrite some parts of PyRe implementation, you can reach it but it is not nice and I guess it is not an option.

**Referencies:**

- [Error-supression](https://pyre-check.org/docs/error-suppression.html)
- [Configuration](https://pyre-check.org/docs/configuration.html)

Answer (score 3):

I believe what you're looking for could be found in [the documentation](https://pyre-check.org/docs/error-suppression.html).
So what you need to do is write a specific comment according to the doc.
in your case something like this would help:

```
# pyre-ignore[16]
here will be the line of code causing the error
```

Answer (score 1):

Another option is to fix this error rather than suppressing it.

Such errors happen when you use classes or attributes, or functions that exist in the `.py` file but are not defined in the appropriate `.pyi` file. In other words, such errors happen on inconsistencies between the source code and the type hint stub. In your case, the `_STRUCT` class was defined in the `struct_pb2.py`, but was not defined in the `.pyi` file supplied by Pyre developers, i.e., `/pyre_check/typeshed/third_party/2and3/google/protobuf/struct_pb2.pyi`.

In such cases, you may try to obtain the `.pyi` files from the developers of the appropriate package and replace the files in the pyre `typeshed` directory. However, the `.pyi` files provided by the developers of packages usually do not annotate classes or methods that start with `_`. According to [PEP 8 -- Style Guide for Python Code | Python.org](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/) a name beginning with a single underscore is reserved for internal use

> _single_leading_underscore: weak "internal use" indicator. E.g., from M import * does not import objects whose names start with an
> underscore.

> Modules that are designed for use via from M import * should use the
> **all** mechanism to prevent exporting globals, or use the older convention of prefixing such globals with an underscore (which you
> might want to do to indicate these globals are "module non-public").

> Use one leading underscore only for non-public methods and instance
> variables.

> Public attributes should have no leading underscores.

> internal interfaces (packages, modules, classes, functions, attributes
> or other names) should still be prefixed with a single leading
> underscore.

If you cannot get the update .pyi file from the developers, or it does not contain definitions for names prefixed with an underscore, you may add these names yourself to the .pyi file supplied by Pyre developers.

There also a small hint at [Errors | Pyre (pyre-check.org)](https://pyre-check.org/docs/errors/#third-party-libraries)

Answer (score 1):

It took too much digging and finally having it pointed out to me directly but you can suppress all errors of a given type at the top of a file with:

```
# pyre-ignore-all-errors[16]
# pyre-ignore-all-errors[56]
```